# Add 0 to Mysql Query Results if time interval has no data

Tags: mysql, aggregation

I have written a query that returns time series data for a graph. The data represents requests coming over a network, we get the data in 30 second intervals, and we are aggregating by 5 minute intervals. Some of these intervals have no info, so the result (of time intervals) will look like the following for some domains when a full set would look like the second list.

```
2017-11-01 11:05:00 
2017-11-01 11:15:00 
2017-11-01 11:35:00 
2017-11-01 11:05:00


2017-11-01 11:10:00
2017-11-01 11:15:00
2017-11-01 11:20:00
2017-11-01 11:25:00
2017-11-01 11:30:00
2017-11-01 11:35:00
```

My question is, could we add to the following query so all of the missing five minute intervals would be present, but the number of requests would be zero. Essentially replacing the missing data with the proper timestamp and 0 corresponding requests?

The batch_id just represents the most recent set of data that we received.

```
select
       DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`)
     , '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') INTERVAL(MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`)) 
       - MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`)) MOD 5) MINUTE as `time`
     , SUM(requests) as requests 
from `raw_graphs` 
where (`batch_id` = 25) group by `time`
```

Comment: This article may help you figure out this problem https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/ (shameless self promotion alert!)

Comment: The usual way to deal with this sort of problem is to join with a _calendar_ table.  In this case, the calendar table would have one entry for every date and 5 minute period.  By left joining the calendar table to your current query, you can bring in all dates/times.

Comment: O. Jones - are you in NBPT??? - me too! small world. Will take a read.